# Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'fn' is not a function, got undefined (problems with Angular service)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-services

I have a problem with an Angular 1.x Service. This is the code:

```
export const MyService = () => {

   //some code
};
```

And when I try to inject that Service into this Controller...

```
export default function MyController(MyService) {
    'ngInject';

    //some code
}
```

...it throws the following error:

```
Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'fn' is not a function, got undefined
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: can you show your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it!! It was just a matter of mistyping

Comment: Please just delete the question then.